# Why is Safari ignoring my session/remember-me cookies?

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, safari, remember-me

On my web-app, some users complain that they have to log in way too often, ranging from every few hours to every few days. Invariably, these users are on Safari. So Safari is clearly doing something weird to my session cookies and my remember-me cookies.

They don't have the problem with other websites, and (as far as I know) this issue started in the last few months, without me updating anything that would affect it. I suspect that some update to Safari has caused it to behave differently, but I'm not sure what to do with it, especially since I don't have Safari on my own computer, so it's hard to test.

Server is node/express, relevant code is

`app.use(session({ // uses cookie connect.sid
  secret: process.env.SESSION_STORE_SECRET,
  store: mongoStore,
  maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(passport.authenticate('remember-me'))`

Aha. I hadn't actually looked at the code, since I didn't expect to find anything given that it works fine in other browsers. But I think that maxAge thing may be the issue. So maybe Safari is fine with `session` cookies but is playing weird with the `remember-me` system... whereas other browsers are working fine with the latter, such that I didn't notice since I don't use Safari.

I'm going to remove the `maxAge` line, since the default doesn't have one at all and that seems to be fine.

[Here's the site](https://complice.co/) if you want to inspect the cookies and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

I think that maxAge thing may be the issue. So maybe Safari is fine with `session` cookies but is playing weird with the `remember-me` system... whereas other browsers are working fine with the latter, such that I didn't notice since I don't use Safari.

I'm going to remove the `maxAge` line, since the default doesn't have one at all and that seems to be fine.